# How to model a button with icons in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I'm using [react-native-icons](https://github.com/corymsmith/react-native-icons) package to include icons with buttons. They have a sample code listed in [example folder](https://github.com/corymsmith/react-native-icons/blob/master/Example/index.ios.js). I'm trying to achieve `onPress` on View but turns out react-native doesn't have `onPress` function for `<View>` component.

I tried using `<TouchableHighlight>` but it can only have single child element in it not two like `<Icon>` and `<Text>` inside.

I also tried using `<Text>` with `<Icon>` and `<Text>` inside but `<Text>` can only have `<Text>` elements inside.

Has anyone have any luck achieving similar functionality ?

[image: Sample Buttons with Icons]

```
<View onPress={this.onBooking} 
  style={styles.button}>
  <Icon
    name='fontawesome|facebook-square'
    size={25}
    color='#3b5998'
    style={{height:25,width:25}}/>
  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign In with Facebook</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you are using [react-native-icons](https://github.com/corymsmith/react-native-icons) module, you can try wrap both your icon and text in a view, then use TouchableHighlight on top of it. Something like:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>{}}>
     <View>
         <Icon ... />
         <Text ... />
     </View>
 </TouchableHighlight>
```

But it will be very easy if you use a relative new module [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons). You can do like:

```
<Icon name="facebook" style={styles.icon}>
   <Text style={styles.text}>Login with Facebook</Text>
</Icon>
```

Comment: I use TouchableOpacity like this:

    `<TouchableOpacity style={} onPress={()=>{}}
         <Icon ... />
         <Text ... />
    </TouchableOpacity>`

Comment: For the react-native-vector-icons, it seems that the Icon does not manage the children. The Text element should be outside, just after the Icon and not inside.

Answer (score 12):

I managed to do it like this. I wonder if there is a better way.

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  btnClickContain: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: '#009D6E',
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 5,
    marginTop: 5,
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  btnContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  btnIcon: {
    height: 25,
    width: 25,
  },
  btnText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: '#FAFAFA',
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginTop: 2,
  }
});

<TouchableHighlight
  onPress={this.onBooking} style={styles.btnClickContain}
  underlayColor='#042417'>
  <View
    style={styles.btnContainer}>
    <Icon
      name='fontawesome|facebook-square'
      size={25}
      color='#042'
      style={styles.btnIcon}/>
    <Text style={styles.btnText}>Sign In with Facebook</Text>
  </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: Hey @msqar, it's been almost 2 years since I had tried again the above code. You can post an edit if you like ;) Back then it worked, now things can be different.

Comment: Yea, im still struggling to make it look good T_T why something so simple is gets this hard? hahaha

Answer (score 10):

Expo [has a](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v35.0.0/guides/icons/#button-component) a `Button` component that does what you want, styling and all:

```
<FontAwesome.Button name="facebook" backgroundColor="#3b5998" onPress={...}>
  Sign in with Facebook
</FontAwesome.Button>
<FontAwesome.Button name="twitter" backgroundColor="#1da1f2" onPress={...}>
  Sign in with Twitter
</FontAwesome.Button>
```

What it looks like running in the iOS simulator:

[image]

If you're not using [Expo](https://expo.io/), study the source and create a similar component.